# Sdk's for getting auth token for posting on facebook / twitter / linked in, then post using nodejs

Tags: ios, node.js, authentication, oauth, openid

I am developing an iOs application, In which user set his social status, that status will post on schedule time( that can be after 1,2... week ) from cronjob(server side is on nodejs ).

Please suggest me is there any sdk for this, using that I can get offline permission(Auth token [that token is required for posting] ).

I know about [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/add/) but it's only sharing things.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073261/ios-facebook-twitter-auth-post-from-php-backend) on stack but that doesn't have answer:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not found any sdk, Finally I did my task as traditional way of Installing all sdk's individually.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search provided some answers.

For Facebook, request permissions using the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/).  Capture the token:

```
[[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken]];
```

For Twitter, there's an [explanation of OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth), and a [GitHub example of reverse OAuth](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample) to use for posting on behalf of a user.

For LinkedIn, there's a [how-to for getting an OAuth token](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-oauth-token), and there's a [GitHub repo for iOS authentication](https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI)

Comment: please read the question , I need all libraries in in one. Btw thanks for it.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, but maybe this is what you are looking for[SimpleAuth](https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth).