# LinkedIn login with Stormpath

Tags: swift, swift2, stormpath

I am able to get the access token of my LinkedIn account in swift using the LinkedIn SDK. How do I authenticate this login with Stormpath?

**[Update]**

let APIURL = "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/**LI_APPLICATION_ID**/accounts"

```
func sendRequestWithJSON(accessToken:String)
{
    let json = [ "providerData" : ["providerId": "linkedin", "accessToken": accessToken] ]


    do {

        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted)

        let username = STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID
        let password = STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

        // create post request
        let url = NSURL(string: APIURL)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


        // insert json data to the request
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                print("Result -> \(result)")

            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        //return task
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I am passing accessToken fetch from linkedin to above function, but it return below result:

**["message": Authentication required., "status": 401, "code": 401, "developerMessage": Authentication with a valid API Key is required., "moreInfo": http://www.stormpath.com/docs/quickstart/connect]**

What's wrong I am doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS linkedin authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491280/ios-linkedin-authentication)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The linked question is asking about vanilla LinkedIn login, while this question is asking about a Stormpath-backed app.

Answer (score 5):

LinkedIn is an interesting beast, since their mobile SDKs have two flaws:

- An end user NEEDS the LinkedIn app to be installed, otherwise the "login" button will redirect the user to the App Store.
- The mobile access token cannot be used on the server. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPsaW.png) from [LinkedIn's iOS documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth)

So - to get auth working on mobile, I would recommend using a server to handle the flow, so you don't have to worry about those two downsides. This is roughly:

1. The app will redirect the user to your webserver.
2. The webserver begins the LinkedIn authentication flow, and redirects the user to LinkedIn.
3. The user logs into LinkedIn, and gets redirected back to your webserver.
4. The webserver reads the response, and exchanges the Authorization Code with LinkedIn for an access token.
5. The webserver redirects your user back to the app, using a custom url scheme to send it the LinkedIn access token.
6. The app uses the LinkedIn access token to login to Stormpath.

Sound complicated? It's actually more straightforward than it seems. I actually wrote some [demo code for this flow using Express.js & Swift](https://github.com/edjiang/stormpath-mobile-linkedin-example) if you want to try it out. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks Edward for your help.
Let me try your provided example (will accept it as answer once done ;) )

Comment: Hi Edward, Can you please tell me what settings i need to do with swift project to run your app? I am not able to run this application on simulator.

Comment: What error are you getting? It should work out of the box.

Comment: My main problem is, i am using linkedin mobile sdk to fetch access token.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use the LinkedIn SDK for iOS? I linked above to LinkedIn's documentation, where they explicitly say it cannot be used on a server, so the LinkedIn SDK unfortunately will not work with Stormpath.

Comment: However, the sample code I created should work for getting LinkedIn sign-in working with Stormpath! Let me know what problems you are having to run the application on the simulator.

Comment: My only requirement is i just want to allow linkedin user to login to my app. And for this I dont want to write anything at server side. Thats why trying to implement it at client end.
But now I understand, I can not validate access token fetch using likedin mobile sdk with stormpath, correct?

Is there any workaround to this?

I have updated question, though.

I am getting the error at http://localhost:3000/
I have no idea how could i run server

Comment: No problem. Try: downloading Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/, then follow the Node.js quickstart at https://api.stormpath.com/ to set your environment variables for Stormpath. Then run steps 4/5 listed in the Git repo's readme.

Comment: so is it mandetory to setup server?
I cant bypass that?
There is no alternative?
As google and facebook with stormpath does not required to setup additional server

Comment: Yes, LinkedIn requires it if you want to use the access token elsewhere like with Stormpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111080/discussion-between-chetan-rane-and-edward-jiang).