# LinkedIn iOS SDK bridge on a swift project, authentication issue

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

I've followed the steps on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491280/ios-linkedin-authentication), also set up the bundle identifier of my app to linkedin apps. I also followed the steps on how to set up the linkedin app id on info.plist.

After clicking my linkedin logging button, linkedin app open but it never ask for a permission and just automatically switch back to my app with this error

```
"error domain=lisdkautherror code=2 "(null)""
```

Am I still missing something? Been searching this a whole day now. They all say the error is about the app id not included on the plist, but I double check it already and all is good.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Man that is a very ambiguous error. I assume it stands for some sort of "linked in authorization error" so it should be coming from the server and shouldn't have anything to do w/ internet connectivity. Im browsing Linked In's sdk docs but can't find a place for auth error codes.

Comment: Did you double check you whitelisted the URL's? It seems like iOS could be doing the redirect back to your app because it doesn't "trust" the app. So it would need to be added to a whitelist. Doublecheck that you did step 4 of that tutorial.

Comment: @NSGangster, yes, i have done both the Whitelisting and the Url for the App Transport Security.

Comment: All of the search results that I found regarding the error, they told to add the bundle identifier to the linkedin app and the app id of linkedin app to ios plist.