# Login with 'LinkedIn' not run in real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linkedin-api

I tried with this pods => ['LinkedinSwift', '~> 1.6.6'](https://github.com/tonyli508/LinkedinSwift) pod 
It worked perfectly in the simulator but not work in real devices.. (Buy clicking button nothing happens even error log is not generated in device).

Here I attached the snap of simulator screen in which works fine.

[image]

and after login, I get the proper response like this.

**Response**

```
<LSResponse - data: {
    emailAddress = "ryangosling@gmail.com";
    firstName = "Ry'n";
    id = fDhWdOnDth;
    lastName = gosling;
    location =     {
        country =         {
            code = in;
        };
        name = "Rajkot Area, India";
    };
    pictureUrl = "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQGFP3uda49gSA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_?e=1528610400&v=beta&t=Hi7cJc9Cba9eWU5gqYZqDeqwnxJWSMBGRHl7hKygK_U";
    pictureUrls =     {
        "_total" = 1;
        values =         (
            "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E00AQHuV79iTxaCew/profile-originalphoto-shrink=1528610400&v=beta&t=fUhfz14_LzubT3JdhuD6UQ358yg7_KgmDv5e7sklTHs"
        );
    };
    positions =     {
        "_total" = 1;
        values =         (
                        {
                company =                 {
                    id = 1467;
                    industry = "Information Technology & Services";
                    name = "NCR Corporation";
                    size = "10001+";
                    ticker = NCR;
                    type = "Public Company";
                };
                id = 1105682753;
                isCurrent = 1;
                location =                 {
                    country =                     {
                        code = us;
                        name = "United States";
                    };
                    name = "Washington D.C. Metro Area";
                };
                startDate =                 {
                    month = 2;
                    year = 2002;
                };
                title = "Web Developer";
            }
        );
    };
}, status code: 200>
```

But when I run in the real device on calling the function, nothing happens.

Please, anyone, help me about LinkedIn login using swift 4.0 (Any other framework or library most welcome..)

I already tried this some other frameworks..

1) [LinkedInLogin Using official framework added into Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491280/ios-linkedin-authentication)
But for this, we must install 'LinkedIn App' in our real device!

2) pod 'LinkedInSignIn' => In this I get the LinkedIn token, but after that getting user profile is not work.
For that, I tried this four URL as well but still not work.

```
let linkedInApi = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json"
let linkedInApi2 = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(public-profile-url)?format=json"
let linkedInApi3 = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"
let linkedInApi4 = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),positions,date-of-birth,phone-numbers,location)?format=json"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my device LinkedIn App install

So 'LinkedinSwift', '~> 1.6.6' framework automatically sign-in via App and after that It can't getUser Profile (may be this is bug).

So I do customised the framework code and changed it, like in way it always open WebView and then I logout manually after getting profile data. Finally I solve this issue.

In this main support of @[iTag](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3326506/itag). That guy help me a lot so I can able to solve this issue. Thanks every one to put your effort and **specially thanks for @iTag.**