# iOS LinkedIn login - createSession callbacks never called

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, linkedin-api

I followed this tutorial [iOS linkedin authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491280/ios-linkedin-authentication) combined with LinkedIn's SDK tutorial. Everything seems to be set well. My app is opening LinkedIn app. OAuth URL callback looks like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
if LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandle(url) {
    return LISDKCallbackHandler.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
return true
```

}

and my onLinkedInButtonClicked method looks like this:

```
@IBAction func doLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth([LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
    print("success called!")
    let session = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session
    }) { (error) -> Void in
        print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

}

After clicking the LinkedIn login button I am redirected to the LinkedIn app and asked for permission. After pressing OK in LinkedIn app I am redirected back to my app but nothing is printed in Xcode's console. I also tried to show alert like this:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Login error",
            message: (message),
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
            handler: nil))

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but it is not appearing as well. It seems like the success or error callback from createSession is not called. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47794323/8346251

Comment: Is there swift solution? I am new to iOS development without objective-c knowledge.

Comment: The McDonal_11's answer has the swift solution